# advantages and disadvantages when dealing with similar data sets

Tags: data-structures, dataset

I have a question about pros and cons when using data structures to represent similar data sets.

**An example scenario:**

We use a data structure to get data from a service. 
The structure looks like this:

```
type Customer = {
CustomerId
CompanyId
GroupId
Status
VerType
Name
Active
TransType
}
```

We need to get all data and present the data to the user. When we save data, the only thing the user can change is the Status. We only need to return CustomerId, CompanyId, GroupId (the primary key composition) and the new Status.

What would you do here? Would you:

1: Create a new structure (see below) and use that separate structure to save the data:

```
type CustomerSave = {
CustomerId
CompanyId
GroupId
Status
}
```

2: Use the same structure as we did when getting the data, but with all other properties set to null.

3: Send the data as separate variables (since the data set might be concidered small enough to do that).

4: Any other ideas?

Note that all structures are fictional, so there is no need for you to comment on the data itself.

Please give your suggestions! I'm curious!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the situation.
If the data is too big you may use the lazy loading methods.
If you create new sub-sets of the structure you may have to map them to the original structure to update them.